Laravel Broadcasting Auth issues while using Reverb
Hi guys,
for the life of me I can't get private and presence channels working with reverb because my authenticated user always comes up as null, this setup worked perfectly with Pusher so I''m convinced it has to do with environment variables, my setup:
docker-compose
services:
    zennbet-queue:
        restart: always
        container_name: zennbet_queue
        networks:
            - zennbet-network
        build:
            context: ..
            target: queue
        volumes:
            - ../:/var/www/html
        env_file:
            - ../.env
        depends_on:
            zennbet-reverb:
                condition: service_started

    zennbet-reverb:
        restart: always
        container_name: zennbet_reverb
        networks:
            - zennbet-network
        build:
            context: ..
            target: reverb
        ports:
            - "8080:8080"
        volumes:
            - ../:/var/www/html
        env_file:
            - ../.env
        depends_on:
            zennbet-provider:
                condition: service_healthy

    zennbet-provider:
        restart: always
        container_name: zennbet_provider
        networks:
            - zennbet-network
        build:
            context: ..
            target: artisan
        ports:
            - "8000:8000"
        volumes:
            - ../:/var/www/html
        environment:
            # Database
            DB_CONNECTION: pgsql
            DB_HOST: zennbet-postgres
            DB_PORT: 5432
            DB_DATABASE: zennbet_postgres
            DB_USERNAME: zennbet_postgres
            DB_PASSWORD: zennbet_postgres

            # Redis
            REDIS_HOST: zennbet-redis
            REDIS_PORT: 6379
            REDIS_PASSWORD: null

            # Drivers
            BROADCAST_DRIVER: reverb
            BROADCAST_CONNECTION: reverb
            CACHE_DRIVER: redis
            QUEUE_CONNECTION: redis
            SESSION_DRIVER: redis

            # App Config
            APP_NAME: laravel
            APP_ENV: local
            APP_DEBUG: true
            APP_URL: http://localhost:8000
            COMPOSER_ALLOW_SUPERUSER: 1
            APP_KEY: base64:FaJv3osf3MWzafZ7pIncxRtq0ADGYqnutDAaYBgh0xc=

            # Logging
            LOG_CHANNEL: stderr
            LOG_LEVEL: debug

            # Reverb Server Config
            REVERB_SERVER_HOST: zennbet_reverb
            REVERB_SERVER_PORT: 8080
            REVERB_HOST: localhost
            REVERB_PORT: 8080

            # Reverb App Config
            REVERB_APP_ID: reverb_app_id
            REVERB_APP_KEY: reverb_app_key
            REVERB_APP_SECRET: reverb_app_secret
            REVERB_SCHEME: http

            # Cookie and Session Config
            SANCTUM_STATEFUL_DOMAINS: "localhost:3000,localhost:8000"
            SESSION_DOMAIN: ".localhost"
            CORS_ALLOWED_ORIGINS: "http://localhost:3000"

        depends_on:
            zennbet-postgres:
                condition: service_healthy
            zennbet-redis:
                condition: service_healthy
        healthcheck:
            test: [ "CMD", "php", "artisan", "migrate:status" ]
            interval: 10s
            timeout: 5s
            retries: 5
            start_period: 10s

    zennbet-postgres:
        image: postgres:latest
        restart: always
        container_name: zennbet_postgres
        networks:
            - zennbet-network
        environment:
            POSTGRES_USER: zennbet_postgres
            POSTGRES_PASSWORD: zennbet_postgres
            POSTGRES_DB: zennbet_postgres
        ports:
            - "5432:5432"
        volumes:
            - zennbet-postgres-data:/var/lib/postgresql/data
        healthcheck:
            test: [ "CMD-SHELL", "pg_isready -U zennbet_postgres" ]
            interval: 10s
            timeout: 5s
            retries: 5
            start_period: 10s

    zennbet-redis:
        image: redis:latest
        restart: always
        container_name: zennbet_redis
        networks:
            - zennbet-network
        ports:
            - "6379:6379"
        volumes:
            - zennbet-redis-data:/data
        healthcheck:
            test: [ "CMD", "redis-cli", "ping" ]
            interval: 10s
            timeout: 5s
            retries: 5
            start_period: 10s

networks:
    zennbet-network:
        driver: bridge

volumes:
    zennbet-postgres-data:
    zennbet-redis-data:

BroadcastServiceProvider,
logging the user here yielded null, even though cookies and headers were set
<?php

namespace App\Providers;

use Illuminate\Support\ServiceProvider;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Broadcast;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class BroadcastServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider
{
    public function boot(Request $request)
    {
        Broadcast::routes();
        require base_path('routes/channels.php');
    }
}
providers.php
<?php

return [
    App\Providers\AppServiceProvider::class,
    Illuminate\Broadcasting\BroadcastServiceProvider::class,
    App\Providers\BroadcastServiceProvider::class,
];

here is a test endpoint to test out my auth, worked great, got back my user as I should
Route::get('/auth-test', function () {
    return response()->json([
        'web_user' => auth('web')->user(),
        'sanctum_user' => auth('sanctum')->user(),
        'default_user' => auth()->user(),
        'session_id' => session()->getId(),
        'session_data' => session()->all()
    ]);
})->middleware(['web', 'auth:sanctum,web']);

and my front-end setup, where NEXT_PUBLIC_PROVIDER = laravel app (https://localhost:8000),
my auth setup works for all other endpoints through cookies, but here it fails
  window.Pusher = Pusher;
  window.Pusher.logToConsole = true;

  window.Echo = new Echo({
    broadcaster: "reverb",
    key: "reverb_app_key",
    wsHost: window.location.hostname,
    wsPort: 8080,
    forceTLS: false,
    enabledTransports: ["ws"],
    disableStats: true,
    cluster: null, // ✅ Add this
    encrypted: false, // ✅ Add this
    withCredentials: true, // ✅ Add this for CORS
    authorizer: (channel: { name: string }) => {
      return {
        authorize: async (socketId: string, callback: Function) => {
          console.log("Authorizing channel:", channel.name); // Add this lin

          try {
            const options = {
              socket_id: socketId,
              channel_name: channel.name,
            };
            const query = new URLSearchParams(options).toString();

            const headers = {
              "X-XSRF-TOKEN": CSRFToken,
            };
            const init = buildRequestOptions(headers);
            const response = await fetch(
              `${process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_PROVIDER}/broadcasting/auth?${query.toString()}`,
              {
                ...init,
                method: "POST",
                body: JSON.stringify(options),
              },
            );
            console.log("Authorized");
            callback(false, await response.json());
          } catch (error) {
            console.log(error);
            callback(true, error as Error);
          }
        },
      };
    },
  });

I'm getting back empty on /broadcasting/auth as auth failed, I should;ve passed and gotten channel and auth data back
